# How to Override Django ManyRelatedManager Methods and Enforce Validations

Tags: python, django, django-models, many-to-many, manyrelatedmanager

I have the following two models that have a Many-to-Many (m2m) relationship. I want to implement validation rules when creating a relationship, particularly when the `Field` object is controlled.

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, editable=False)
    fields = models.ManyToManyField("Field", related_name="categories")
```

```py
class Field(models.Model):
    controller = models.ForeignKey(
        "self",
        models.CASCADE,
        related_name="dependents",
        null=True,
        blank=True,
    )
    label = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

When creating a relationship between a `Category` and a `Field` objects via the manager's `add()` method, I would like to validate that, for a controlled field, the controller field must already be associated with the category.

When creating via the `set()` method, I would like to validate for any controlled field in the list, the controller field must also be in the list, OR is already associated with the category.

```py
# Category
category = Category.objects.create(name="Cars", slug="cars")

# Fields
brand_field = Field.objects.create(name="brand", label="Brand")
model_field = Field.objects.create(name="model", label="Model", controller=brand_field)

# controller should already be associated or raises an exception
category.fields.add(model_field)

# Controller must be inclded in the list as well,
# OR already associated, or raise an exception
category.fields.set([model_field])
```

Where can I enforce this constraints? I'm thinking of overriding `ManyRelatedManager`'s `add()` and `set()` methods but I do not understand how they're coupled to Django model or field.

### Alternatively

If it's not viable to override the `ManyRelatedManager` methods, where in the `ModelAdmin` can I intercept objects before they're saved so that I can run these checks?

Comment: Do you have to use the built-in `.add()` and `.set()` methods? Have you considered implementing your own `.add_field()` and `.set_field()` methods in `Category` model?

Comment: Yeah, I would have implemented custom methods, but these specific models are exclusively managed by the admin. End-users have read-only permissions on them. As a result, we heavily rely on Django admin for management. Given the thousands of objects to handle, the potential for errors is high, and even a minor data inconsistency could disrupt our operations, necessitating strict validation.

Comment: I see. I can't think of a way other than using the [`m2m_changed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.m2m_changed) signal when `action == "pre_add"`.

Comment: Please check the bottom of my original question, the "Alternatively" section I've just included.

Comment: As I mentioned above you can use the signal handlers, which should work with both admin and non-admin ORM operations.

Comment: Why not use form validaton for this? If you're open to enforcing this constraint in the admin only (instead of enforcing it on a model level), then form validation is the obvious way to go.

Comment: That's exactly what I've done now.